# CountIF statement in SharePoint

Tags: calendar, calculated-column-formula, comparison

I am trying to make something like a CountIF statement in SharePoint for the purpose of counting specific choices made in a drop down category for a calendar event.

Currently, when I make a new event, in this case, a Vacation list of employees, I select a dropdown that has a list of positions. ex: "Machinist", Carpenter", Clerk".

I am trying to code something that counts the number of times each category is selected and make sure to limit them to a max number per day.

For example, if I add 5 people within the same day and I try to add 6th I want it to deny it and say "limit reached" or something to that effect.

I assume that I may be able to make a category in the calendar to count choices in a drop down category ex: 
`IF([Category],"Machinist">5,"Limit Reached","Accepted"]` and somehow maybe add an AND statement comparing "Start Date" and "End date" to make sure that no more than 5 Machinists can be selected for events in the same day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SP is not Excel, Formulas can not do any calculations across Rows

So there is not COUNTIF

Typically this is solved by a Workflow looping through the Items

But it can also be solved by Client Side OR Server Side Code

Search for `limit entries` here on SO,
I have answered the use case several times with some out-of-the-box SP thinking